# Nonreflecting boundaries for a wave equation simulation

Tags: physics, numeric, numerical-methods, physics-engine, numerical-integration

I am implementing a simulation of the [wave equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) using an array to discretely model a spatial region in which waves can propagate. Currently, waves reflect off the boundaries of the spatial region. However, I want to eliminate this reflection so that waves appear to propagate off forever.

I am aware there are many academic papers discussing nonreflecting / absorbing boundary conditions (e.g. perfectly matched layers?), but most seem to focus on analytic solutions. I cannot figure out how to implement nonreflecting boundaries numerically in my simulation. This is the code I am writing:

```
for (var i = 1; i < width - 1; ++i) {
    for (var j = 1; j < height - 1; ++j) {
        var d2f_dx2 = f[i + 1][j] - f[i][j] * 2 + f[i - 1][j];
        var d2f_dy2 = f[i][j + 1] - f[i][j] * 2 + f[i][j - 1];
        var d2f_dt2 = c2[i][j] * (d2f_dx2 + d2f_dy2);
        df_dt[i][j] += d2f_dt2;
    }
}
for (var i = 1; i < width - 1; ++i) {
    for (var j = 1; j < height - 1; ++j) {
        f[i][j] += df_dt[i][j];
    }
}
```

where `f` is the field, `df_dt` is the partial derivative of the field with respect to time, `d2f_dt2` is the second partial derivative of the field with respect to time, `d2f_dx2` is the second partial derivative of the field in the x direction, and `d2f_dy2` is the second partial derivative of the field in the y direction.

Does anyone know how I can adjust this code to have nonreflecting boundaries?

Comment: I do not believe the code above shows the (x,y) boundary constraints you are seeking to eliminate unless the coefficient matricies for df/dt, dx/dt or dy/dt become asymptotic or damped. Looking, I cannot see any hard boundary in the code above that would cause a reversal in direction for either wave velocity or acceleration. Can you post the relevant parts of the wave equation you are using (yes I looked at the wiki, but the multitude of possible boundary conditions make your code non-specific). Also, can you post a few lines of output around the inflection points for f(x) and f(y)?

Comment: Let me clarify. you have `f[i + 1][j] - f[i][j] * 2 + f[i - 1][j];` x acceleration and `f[i][j + 1] - f[i][j] * 2 + f[i][j - 1];` for y. Look at your conditions. For x, any time `((f[i][j] * 2 ) > (f[i + 1][j] + f[i - 1][j]))` you will get a reversal in magnitude of acceleration. For y, any time `((f[i][j] * 2) > (f[i][j + 1] + f[i][j - 1]))` you will get a reversal in y. You will have to check where the condition `f[i][j] * 2` is incorporated into your equation. That is the only term that will cause reflection if all coefficients are positive.

Answer (score 0):

After clearing a few 25 year old cobwebs, the solution to your problem will depend on your setting the equations to satisfy the following initial conditions and condition at infinity. It has been far to long for me to translate initial and infinite boundary conditions into the partial differential and then into code for you, but knowing the correct boundary conditions to apply will provide the numerical model your are trying to create. Hopefully this will help.

For the undamped non-reflecting condition, the boundary value problem you are looking to model is described in the wikipedia article you site under the last paragraph of [**The_Sturm-Liouville_formulation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#The_Sturm-Liouville_formulation). The The_Sturm-Liouville formulation itself may not provide the proper model, but **the boundary conditions discussed** in the last paragraph under the heading are those you must satisfy. The derivation is explained in a single dimension, but as noted in the article, the numerical solution for the one-dimension problem can be extended to any number of dimensions.

**Boundary Conditions for Undamped Infinite Propagation**

```
boundary value at t=0 == value at t=infinity after X whole periods, where
y = Asin(Bx - C) + D or y = Acos(Bx - C) + D.
```

The solution for `f(x)t` and `f(y)t` will be periodic trigonomic functions with the waves propagating on to infinity. If you think about it, the conditions are clear. At any point in time, the wave you wish to describe is simply an undamped periodic harmonic that will be modeled on a sine, cosine, etc.. The only difference in description of the wave at any point in time will be amplitude and phase as it cycles though a normal period. The identity of which trigonomic function will satisfy your initial condition will depend on the phase angle and shift at time t=0. The boundary condition as time approaches infinity will be that same function after a whole number of periods are complete.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this properly. I guess the question I'm trying to ask is how I should process the grid points at the boundaries of the spatial region (i.e. where i == 0 or j == 0 or i == width - 1 or j == height - 1), including values of the field and their derivatives, in order to prevent waves from reflecting off the boundaries of the simulation.

Comment: I love problems that you can really wrap your head around (or vice versa). Short answer: No different than at i,j == 0+1 or i,j == (width -2, height -2). That is not intended to be factitious. You will have a wave state at time t=0. It's state will either be the continuation of a wave that arrived at i,j=0 at an arbitrarily chosen t=0, or it will be a new wave, the result of a new disturbance. Regardless, if you are wanting to simply model propagation of that wave from then on, then the propagation vector for the wave will remain constant and unchanged, as a sine/cosine wave for all i,j.

Comment: So basically you have a sinusoid that you will model from t=0 to t=INF, all normal boundary interaction for purposes of the wave simulation, would not be included in your calculations, you would just want to describe the wave state at any point in time, including at i,j = width, height. Consider yourself an observer at i,j = width, height, what you would see would simply be a wave rolling by and a new wave following it. At that point i,j you would simply see a sine or cosine where x is fixed at width and y is the normal amplitude cycle over the course of the wave period.

Comment: I guess another key to understanding the relationship between i,j = 0 and i,j at width, height, is to know that the wave will be periodic over a given distance 2pi. Once you have your wavelength, if width or height is a multiple of wavelength, then at 0 and width,height, the characteristics of the wave (amplitude, phase shift, etc..) will be exactly the same. If width, height is not a multiple of wavelength, then at width, height, your wave will be described by the change in the wave between the last complete period and width, height.